# Querying DynamoDB without PrimaryKey with Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I want to query my DynamoDB with a lambda function running python.

DynamoDB Table (Name: Testing-Table):

- **user_id** (String) **PrimaryKey**
- status (String)
- destination (String)

I want to query the table as it is in my code. I want the lambda function to return me all the **user_id**'s that has their **status** attribute with **active**.

```
table = dynamodb.Table('Testing-Table')
def lambda_handler(event, context):

response = table.query (
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('status').eq('active')
)

for i in response['Items']:
    print(i['user_id'],":",i['status'])

#return 'listing results'
```

I've also added a new index:
[image: Indexes]

I tried creating a table with **status** as primary key, and my code worked... but primarykey's must be unique, so when I try to create a new item in my table, I cant set **status** as active again.

If necessary, I will add more information to the question. I would thank for a little help.

--**Edit**--
My code works *only* if **status** is the PrimaryKey of my table.

*My question is*: Can I query my DynamoDB table using **status** PartitionKey instead of the PrimaryKey **used_id**? And most important...How is it done?

Comment: What is your question? Does the code snippet that you have added works?

Comment: It works, but it does not do what I need. I need to filter active, inactive states. Obtaining as a result of the Lambda execution the user_id of my table.

Answer (score 10):

I've found what I was looking for:

I had to add the *IndexName* in my code like this.

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('Testing-Table')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

response = table.query (
    IndexName='status-index',
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('status').eq('active')
)

for i in response['Items']:
    print(i['user_id'],":",i['status'])
```

Here is an image of the result:

[image: results]

Answer (score 3):

An alternative method exists for locating items without relying on the *partition key* or *sort key*. If you're interested in understanding the functionality of these keys, you can refer to this [source.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/)

The previous solution utilized the **table.query** function. However, this solution will employ the **table.scan** function. For further information on *scanning*, you can consult the official documentation [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html#querying-and-scanning).

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('table_name')

response = table.scan(
    FilterExpression=Attr('attribute_name').eq('value of attribute you want to find')
)
items = response['Items']
print(items)
```

To ensure completeness, don't forget to include the import statement `from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr`

If you're interested in exploring the various methods and options available with the **scan** function, you can refer to the documentation provided [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb/client/scan.html)

Also, keep a note that

> *scan is relatively slower than query in comparison*